# Yii formatting date and filters

Tags: php, yii

I have an date field that need to be presented as day/month/year and saved as year-month-date.
I thought in using CFilter for that but since it apply a function after the action it would be executed before the renderization.

Should I put it on an event, is there a default approach for filtering input data and formatting the output data in yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to pass your information to a CGridView / CDetailView as a type of date:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'=>'checkout',
        'type'=>'date',
    ),
),
```

Passing in a type then formats it with the corresponding formatDate function CFormatter.  It's incredibly handy / flexible.  That way you don't even have to convert your dates to a different format.  More info here: https://github.com/samdark/a-guide-to-yii-grids-lists-and-data-providers/blob/master/grid-columns.md