# zii.widgets.CDetailView to format date

Tags: php, yii

As a zii.widgets.CDetailView to format a date to the right I want, not take the form of a database?

**Update**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    ...
    'create_time',
    'update_time',
),
)); ?>
```

Displays the date in the form of

```
Create Time: 2012-10-03 22:49:01
Update Time: 2012-10-05 20:24:01
```

I want to form

```
Create Time: 22:49, 3 Oct 2012
Update Time: 20:24, 5 Oct 2012
```

Comment: explain more what is your problem and paste some code

Comment: maybe add a picture with expected output? or atleast rephrase question, this: `bring a date to the right I mean, not take the form of a database?` is not very clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDetailView uses the Yii::app()->format which doesn't contain the DateFormatter.

You need to use a function to achieve this.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    ...
    array(
       'name'=>'create_time',
       'value'=>Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('HH:ss, dd MMM yyyy',$model->create_time) ,  
     ),
    'update_time',
),
)); ?>
```

this is just a sample, the formats might be different, but it is a good help for you.

Comment: Thank you for your example, little to correct the line
    'value' => Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format('HH:ss, dd MMM yyyy',$model->create_time)

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning on using that specific format in many places (i.e., more than 1 ;-), it's probably worth adding a custom function to the format object.

More info here:
[Yii formating date and filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891629/yii-formating-date-and-filters/11909538#11909538)

but in essense what it would allow you to do is specify it this way:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name'=>'checkout',
        'type'=>'myCustomDate',
    ),
),
```

I find this feature of the CGridView is a incredibly useful feature that is hardly known about in the Yii community.